# Jenkins Audit to Database Plugin to use with Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, jenkins

I want to use the Audit to Database Plugin to record the build information to database. I have installed the plugin properly and below is my config:

JDBC Driver class:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

JDBC Url :jdbc:oracle:thin:@databaseserver.com:XXXX:opsd

username: username

password: password

I have place the ojdbc6.jar in $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/audit2db/WEB-INF/lib location. 
When I click on test connection, I get the error as org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: I am able to successfully make the connection after I downloaded fresh ojdbc jars. ojdbc6_g.jar and ojdbc6.jar. Now when I click on Advance and general DDL, I get the error as **jenkins_audit2db.ddl (No such file or directory)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing Jenkins inside Tomcat, you can caonfigure Oracle JDBC for Tomcat. Download the JARs from Oracle.com and copy them (ojdbc6.jar and ucp.jar) in $TOMCAT/lib and restart Tomcat .
After this action you will be able to configure Oracle JDBC for Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In our case, using Tomcat, Cesar SAC's advice was good.

Furthermore we had an error running a job on the Master (checked on jenkins 1.653 and 1.565.1 and DB oracle 11.2.0.3): org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("XXXX"."JENKINS_BUILD_NODE"."NAME").
When you launch a job on a Node or on the Master, the plugin writes one line each Node/Master on the table JENKINS_BUILD_NODE. Unfortunately the name of the Node for the Master is ‘null’ and this causes an error. We solved removing the NOT NULL constraint on NAME column and editing the field with the name of the Master. There's an open issue about this here: [audit2db-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/audit2db-plugin/issues/9)